# WCF service and client side config file

Tags: wcf, wcf-configuration

i am new in wcf so often read many article on wcf from various site. recently i was seeing a wcf chat code and saw the config code difference at service and client end.

is it mandatory that service end & client end config should look similar in terms of config settings.

here i am pasting two config code just tell me why so difference in config setting at service & client end?

### service end config details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="ChatSvc.ChatService" behaviorConfiguration="ChatServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8085/Chat" binding="netTcpBinding" 
                    contract="ChatSvc.IChat" />
                <!--bindingConfiguration="PortSharingBinding"-->

                <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8085/Chat/mex"
                          binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <!--<bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="PortSharingBinding" portSharingEnabled="true">
                    <security mode="None"/>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>-->
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ChatServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

### client end config details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Off, ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="d:\cs\cs 4\cs 4-1\work\ChatApplication_FT - ChunkedBufferedFT\simpleclient\TracingFiles\app_tracelog.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp, Callstack">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="false" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IChat" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
          transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864"
          maxBufferSize="524288" maxConnections="100" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="268435456"
            maxArrayLength="67108864" maxBytesPerRead="67108864" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="20:00:10"
            enabled="true" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign">
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IChat1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="20:00:10"
            enabled="true" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign">
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8085/Chat" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IChat" contract="ChatSvc.IChat"
        name="NetTcpBinding_IChat" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

now my question is that there is so many setting at client end but there is little setting at service end.....how is it possible. does the service works properly?

i am new in wcf. so please guide me in details. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the excess in the client config just means that WCF diagnostics have at one point been enabled for the client.

For instance, the whole `<system.diagnostics>` section on the client configuration is entirely optional and can be removed.

Comment: if the system.diagnostics can be remove then why it is there in config file?

Comment: at the client side <netTcpBinding> section has lots of setting but at the service end there is nothing such exist....does it not make any problem ? i guess the service & client both end should have same setting for <netTcpBinding> section....am i right?

Comment: what is the meaning to have the <netTcpBinding>  settings at service end and as well as client end?

Comment: If you enable diagnostics and then disable it later, the settings section usually remains in the .config file - the `SwitchValue` on the `Source` element is just set to off. In general, virtually every WCF setting has a default value that takes effect if there is no explicit value in the config file.